# In PHP, how to setup multi-threading or multi-processing to send emails at high speed via AWS SES using AWS multicore Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am building an lightweight MailChimp like app to send emails.
I use Amazon SES. The app is hosted on AWS (multi core Linux instance).
How to best write php to send emails at rapid rate by using multi-threading and multi-processing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS PHP SDK offers support for [promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html) based on the [guzzle promises](https://github.com/guzzle/promises) implementation and the [`CommandPool`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/commands.html#command-pool) to manage concurrent command execution.

If the PHP language is optional for the email sending component in your application I'd recommend taking a look at [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) which would allow you to scale email processing to your maximum workload needs without needing to manage concurrency. Performance would also be highly predictable. Node.js, Python, Java and C# are currently supported in Lambda.

Comment: Curious if the link needs to go via google ad services for the AWS Lambda link?

Comment: Hi @DaveMaple: Can you please suggest which of Node.js, Python, Java and C# is easiest to use with AWS Lambda?

Comment: They are all pretty easy to use. If you want to build on lambda I'd recommend evaluating the code competency of your team and selecting a Lambda supported language that they are best able to code, test and support.

Comment: Anecdotally, I can say that most PHP developers I've worked with have some Javascript experience. Consequently Node.js might be an easy way to get started building some Lambda components if PHP is the core competency you're working with currently.